# Why doesn't this function call print anything?

Tags: python, function

Why doesn't this call print anything? I am using python 3.

The goal of the question is not to print something but to understand the language better. 
I am looking for language rule(s) that tells how those triple quotes are supposed to be interpreted according to the language specification.
And if there  is difference between different versions of specs, please state the  difference.

```
def my_function(s):
    """size = s.size()"""
    print "a" 
    size = len(s)
    print size
    return


my_function("abc")
```

Comment: I hope the actual code doesn't have smart quotes.

Comment: The function without fancy quoting works perfectly fine. Are you saying *nothing happens* when you run it?

Comment: try running it: http://ideone.com/NUixQD

Comment: On repl.it nothing happened.  Just now, I tried at https://ideone.com/ and it worked.

Comment: Where are you running it? It works fine for me, are you running it with nohup?

Comment: After i removed the quotes it , it gave me clear error that print needs parenthesis. with both changes it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i used parenthesis,  removed quotes it worked.

```
def my_function(s):
    print("a") 
    size = len(s)
    print(size)
    return

my_function("abc")
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is python 3. You should be using `print("a")` not `print "a"`

Answer (score -1):

That obviously prints at least "a"; so my guess is that you have it running detached from standard output (e.g. as a daemon) somewhere.

Comment: Not in Python 3, it doesn't; print is just a function there, and thus needs parentheses.